# How to obtain zero-rate(spot-rate)curve from YTM matrix

Tags: interest-rate, yield-curve

I'm studying about the yield curve now.
In particular, I am studying bootstrapping methods to obtain spot rate curve(zero curve).
If several bonds and their coupon rate are given, I know how to calculate zero rates and to obtain its curve,
but if YTM matrix is given, I want to know how to calculate zero rate.
for instance,

[image]

I don't even understand why YTM and Spot rate are different when year is between 0.25 and 0.75.
Because coupon is not paid for less than a year, yield rate and spot rate are the same.
Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: yes. But, for zero coupon bonds, yield rate is the same as coupon rate, isn't it?

Comment: No, zero coupons do not _have_ a coupon rate because they do not pay a coupon. That's why they're calls "zero coupon" bonds.